# WCF service error deserializing object

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a WCF web service that is currently accepting a JSON object of strings where one of the key/value pairs contains a Base 64 encoded string of an image binary data.

When the web service receive the request it throws the following error:

> The exception message is 'There was an error deserializing the object of type. The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data.

I've followed some of the solutions other people have suggested and my Web.Config now has a custom binding:

```
 <bindings>
   <webHttpBinding>
     <binding name="LongWebHttpBinding" 
          maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
       <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
           maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
           maxArrayLength="2147483647"
           maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
           maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
     </binding>
   </webHttpBinding>
 </bindings>
```

With an endpoint configured as follows:

```
 <services>
   <service name="GenericService">
     <endpoint address=""
               behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior"
               binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="LongWebHttpBinding"
               contract="IGenericService" />               
   </service>    
 </services>
```

According to all the other suggestions setting `bindingConfiguration` should resolve the error message I'm getting.

Are there any further steps I can take to try and sort this out?

Comment: Is it still not working after you made the above changes?

Comment: Make sure that `name` attribute in your `service` element contains type name with namespaces (or full type name if referenced from non local assembly). Otherwise your configuration is not used.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka - I never knew that (though I always use the full namespace).

Comment: @LadislavMrnka It looks like the issue was because I wasn't using the full namespace, so as you said the configuration wasn't being used.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still having problems after the new settings, you might want to adjust the `maxItemsInObjectGraph` attribute in the `<dataContractSerializer>` section of the jsonBehavior you defined.

[dataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa749852.aspx)

However, I believe if that is the issue the exception would tell you that - not sure as I've never had to adjust anything other than maxReceivedMessageSize or maxStringContentLength.

Answer (score 0):

As Ladislav Mrnka the issue turned out to be that I wasn't using the full namespace of the service when entering it in the Web.Config.

Once I added the full namespace it appears to be working correctly.

Thanks for your help